# Show that the gcd of $(n^2, n^2 + n + 1) = 1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

We know $(a,\;b)$ = $(a-kb,\;b)$, with $(x,\;y)$ meaning the greatest common divisor of x and y.

$(n^2,\;n^2 + n + 1)$ = $(n^2,\;(n+1)^2 - n)$

Let $d\;|\;n^2$ and let $d\;|\;((n+1)^2 -\;n)$
Then $d\;|\;n+1$, since by linear combination theorem $d\;|\;n^2$ and $d\;|\;(n^2+n+1)$ implies by subtraction that $d\;|\;(n+1)$

Also, since $d\;|\;n^2$, then $d\;|\;n$

Since $d\;|\;n$ then again by linear combination theorem $d\;|\;(n+1)^2$
$d\;|\;(n+1)^2$ implies $d\;|\;(n+1)$
$d\;|\;n$ and $d\;|\;(n+1)$ implies $(d,n) = 1$

Is this proof correct? Seems legit to me. This is my first proof typed out in MathJAX directly, and it started as my asking where to go from the "Also, since ..." but then I managed to complete it!

Comment: You can salvage things by saying if a number $\gt 1$ divides both, then some **prime** $p$ divides both. So Since $p$ divides $n^2$, it follows that $p$ divides $n$, so $p$ divides $n^2+n$, so $p$ divides $1$.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not correct, e.g. $\,d\mid n^2\,\Rightarrow\,d\mid n\,$ is true only for squarefree $\,d.$ Instead, note that $\,n^2+n+1 = n(n+1)+1\,$ is coprime to $\,n,$ so also coprime to $\,n^2,\,$   by Euclid's Lemma.

Or: $\ (n^2,n(n^2)-1) = (n^2,-1)=1,\,$ so $\,n^2\,$ is coprime to all factors of $\,n^3-1,\,$ viz. $\,n^2+n+1.$

Comment: Is the method of picking some arbitrary d that divides both a good way to proceed however?

Comment: Is there a lemma that if d|a, then d does not divide a+1 ?

Comment: @Seg A common divisor of $1+a$ and $a$ divides their difference $1+a-a = 1$. Working modulo a common divisor $d$ can be effective in many cases.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Euclidean Algorithm for Greatest Common Divisor:

$$n^2 + n + 1 = n^2 + (n+1)$$
$$n^2 = (n-1)(n+1) + 1$$

Hence the greatest common divisor is $1$.

Another way is to assume $d \mid n^2$ and $d \mid n^2 + n + 1$, where $d$ is prime number. Now $d$ divides their difference so we have:

$$d \mid n^2 + n + 1 - n^2 \implies d \mid n+1$$

Now since $d \mid n^2 \implies d \mid n$, we get that $d$ divides consecutive numbers, which is possible only for $d = 1$. Hence the proof.

Comment: That's what I did but d|n^2 -> d|n is only true for squarefree d, as per Bill Dubuque above.

Comment: @Segmentationfault If $d$ is prime than $d \mid n^2 \implies d \mid n$. $d$ in the second case doesn't mean GCD, it's just a prime divisor of both numbers.

Comment: @Segmentationfault Also you can always rely on Euclidean Algorithm as I posted it's fairly simple and easy.

Comment: @Stefan The Euclidean algorithm will not always help on *symbolic* gcds like this.

Comment: @BillDubuque Do you know of a good example? It would come in handy (very) frequently.

Comment: @BillDubuque Maybe, but I think for this problem it's the most appropriate solution due it's simplicity.

Answer (score 2):

$$
n\,\color{#C00}{n^2}-(n-1)\,\color{#C00}{\left(n^2+n+1\right)}=1
$$

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the Euclidean algorithm directly:
$$
  \gcd(n^2,n^2+n+1)
 =\gcd(n^2,n+1)
 =\gcd((n+1)(n-1)+1,n+1)
 =\gcd(1,n+1)=1
$$